# Space or tab then it should not be considered as a character

Tags: objective-c

I am having text view in my app. I need to validate input of a text view. The rules are as below

- Tab/Space cannot be accepted in the begining of the text entry
- Tab/Space can be accepted in the middle and end of the text entry
- Max characters accepted can be 256

How do I develop this, first character filteration logic ?

---

I have written following code in my app but it's still not giving me proper output ...Can anybody tell me where is the mistake???

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
        {
            NSString *rawString = [textView text];

```
        NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];

        NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];

        if ([trimmed length] == 0) 
            {

                 // Text was empty or only whitespace.

            }

        NSLog(@"length = %d",[trimmed length]);
        [self.scrollView adjustOffsetToIdealIfNeeded];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *string = [txtview text];;
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%d",trimmedString.length);
```